# Script set to run in docker container is also running on host machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, sh, envsubst

So what I wanted to do is using "COPY script.sh script.sh" (copy script from hos to container and execute) but when executing script in container , seems this script is also executing on host machine.

Below is Dockerfile :

```
FROM almalinux/almalinux:latest


RUN mkdir /opt/confluent 
RUN mkdir /opt/confluent-hub

#Confluent Home
ENV CONFLUENT_HOME=/opt/confluent

ENV KAFKA_CONFIG=$KAFKA_CONFIG
ENV ZOOKEEPER_CONFIG=$ZOOKEEPER_CONFIG
ENV SCHEMA_REGISTRY_CONFIG=$ZOOKEEPER_CONFIG
ENV CONNECT_CONFIG=$CONNECT_CONFIG

# Zookeeper

ENV ZOOKEEPER_DATA_DIR=$ZOOKEEPER_DATA_DIR
ENV ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=$ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT

#Kafka

ENV BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=$BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS
ENV KAFKA_SERVER_BROKER_ID=$KAFKA_SERVER_BROKER_ID
ENV ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT_IP_PORT=$ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT_IP_PORT
ENV KAFKA_SERVER_LOG_DIR=$KAFKA_SERVER_LOG_DIR

# schmea registry
ENV KAFKASTORE_TOPIC=$KAFKASTORE_TOPIC
ENV PROTOCOL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=$PROTOCOL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS
ENV SCHEMA_REGISTRY_GROUP_ID=$SCHEMA_REGISTRY_GROUP_ID
ENV SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LEADER_ELIGIBILITY=$SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LEADER_ELIGIBILITY

# Kafka connect
ENV CONNECT_REST_PORT=$CONNECT_REST_PORT
ENV CONNECT_OFFSETS=$CONNECT_OFFSETS
ENV CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER=$CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER
ENV SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=$SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL
ENV CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER=$CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER
ENV SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENER=$SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENER
ENV CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/share/java/,$CONFLUENT_HOME/share/confluent-hub-components/


# install openjdk8

RUN dnf update -y && dnf install epel-release  -y
RUN dnf install wget zip moreutils gettext unzip java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 -y

# install conflunet

WORKDIR $CONFLUENT_HOME
RUN wget https://packages.confluent.io/archive/6.1/confluent-community-6.1.1.tar.gz -P .
RUN tar -xvzf confluent-community-6.1.1.tar.gz
RUN mv confluent-6.1.1/* .
RUn rm -rf confluent-6.1.1 confluent-community-6.1.1.tar.gz

# install confluent hub

RUN wget http://client.hub.confluent.io/confluent-hub-client-latest.tar.gz -P /opt/confluent-hub
WORKDIR /opt/confluent-hub 
RUN tar -xvzf confluent-hub-client-latest.tar.gz 
RUN rm -rf confluent-hub-client-latest.tar.gz
ENV CONFLUENT_HUB /opt/confluent-hub/bin

# Export path

ENV PATH $PATH:$CONFLUENT_HOME:$CONFLUENT_HUB

# install jdbc connector

COPY confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-10.1.0.zip $CONFLUENT_HOME/share/confluent-hub-components/
RUN unzip $CONFLUENT_HOME/share/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-10.1.0.zip
RUN rm -rf confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-10.1.0.zip

# Copy confleunt config to docker

WORKDIR $CONFLUENT_HOME
COPY config/* config/

# startup

COPY startup.sh ./startup.sh
RUN chmod +x ./startup.sh
CMD ./startup.sh
```

Below is startup.sh which replaces environment variables in config files and starts kafka service but this script when run in container is replacing values on host config file :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Substitue environment variables in actual $CONFLUENT_HOME/configs
envsubst  < $CONFLUENT_HOME/config/zookeeper.properties | sponge $CONFLUENT_HOME/config/zookeeper.properties
envsubst  < $CONFLUENT_HOME/config/server.properties | sponge $CONFLUENT_HOME/config/server.properties
envsubst  < $CONFLUENT_HOME/config/schema-registry.properties | sponge $CONFLUENT_HOME/config/schema-registry.properties
envsubst  < $CONFLUENT_HOME/config/connect-avro-standalone.properties | sponge $CONFLUENT_HOME/config/connect-avro-standalone.properties

# start zookeeper
$CONFLUENT_HOME/bin/zookeeper-server-start -daemon $ZOOKEEPER_CONFIG

sleep 2

# start kafka broker
$CONFLUENT_HOME/bin/kafka-server-start -daemon $KAFKA_CONFIG

sleep 2

# start schema registry
$CONFLUENT_HOME/bin/schema-registry-start -daemon $SCHEMA_REGISTRY_CONFIG

sleep 2

# start kafka connect
$CONFLUENT_HOME/bin/connect-standalone -daemon $CONNECT_CONFIG $CONFLUENT_HOME/etc/kafka/connect-file-sink.properties

sleep 2

while :
do
    echo "Confluent Running "
    sleep 5
done
```

docker-compose :

```
version : "3.9"
services:
        confluent-community:
                build: ./
                environment:
                        - KAFKA_CONFIG=$CONFLUENT_HOME/config/server.properties
                        - ZOOKEEPER_CONFIG=$CONFLUENT_HOME/config/zookeeper.properties
                        - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_CONFIG=$CONFLUENT_HOME/config/schema-registry.properties
                        - CONNECT_CONFIG=$CONFLUENT_HOME/config/connect-avro-standalone.properties
                        - CONNECT_REST_PORT=8083
                        - CONNECT_OFFSETS=$CONFLUENT_HOME/data/connect/connect.offsets
                        - CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
                        - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=http://localhost:8081
                        - CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
                        - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENER=http://0.0.0.0:8081
                        - KAFKASTORE_TOPIC=_schemas
                        - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_GROUP_ID=SCHEMA_REGISTRY_A
                        - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LEADER_ELIGIBILITY=true
                        - PROTOCOL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
                        - ZOOKEEPER_DATA_DIR=$CONFLUENT_HOME/data/zookeeper
                        - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181
                        - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=localhost:9092
                        - KAFKA_SERVER_BROKER_ID=0
                        - ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT_IP_PORT=localhost:2181
                        - KAFKA_SERVER_LOG_DIR=$CONFLUENT_HOME/data/kafka-logs
                          # ports:
                          #- "9092:9092"
                          # - "8081:8081"
                          #- "8083:8083"
                network_mode: "host"
                        
                volumes:
                        - ~/Documents/confluent/docker-logs:/opt/confluent/logs
                        - ~/Documents/confluent/config:/opt/confluent/config
                        - ~/Documents/confluent/docker-data:/opt/confluent/data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bind-mount configuration files into a container

```yaml
volumes:
  - ~/Documents/confluent/config:/opt/confluent/config
```

the files in the container *are* the files on the host.  When your startup script uses `envsubst` to rewrite the configuration files, there's not a separate copy in the container, so it rewrites the files on the host as well.

If you use a separate directory instead:

```yaml
volumes:
  - ~/Documents/confluent/config:/opt/confluent/config-templates
```

Then your script can read the files in that directory, and write to a non-volume directory:

```sh
for f in "$CONFLUENT_HOME/config-templates/*"; do
  ff=$(basename "$f")
  envsubst <$f >"$CONFLUENT_HOME/config/$ff"
done
```

(Run the four processes in four separate containers, without using a `-daemon` option so they're the single foreground process in their respective containers.  You shouldn't need to configure any of the filesystem paths or inject them at run time; the `*_CONFIG` environment variables, for example, can be safely left at their default values, or if they *must* be set, set them only in the `Dockerfile`).